# "Things to do around here" Map

Tags: wordpress, maps, leaflet

i'm currently trying to find the best way to create a simple and elegant "things to do in the area" map. I did such a thing before in a webapp myself with leaflet/backbone, however i thought there might be a wordpress plugin for this that i can use? Googling didn't really bring something up for me, the directory listings i found would probably be quite of an overkill...Does anyone have an idea or experience with building something like that? I will be forever thankful for any pointers and hints. Cheers and love

Answer (score 0):

This is [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-google-maps/) of the many options that are available in Wordpress's plugin directory. All those plugins are open source so you can change them as you wish.